# Yii2 javascript load order

Tags: jquery, yii2

I have ActiveForm inside my view, which i validate inside the mode, using `$this->addError`. However, when i load the page with my active form i see in debug console:

```
TypeError: window.jQuery is not a function    yii.js:520:1
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined    yii.validation.js:452:1
TypeError: $ is undefined    yii.activeForm.js:14:5
jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function @http://localhost:8888/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=14982:770:1
l@http://localhost:8888/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:29373
a/</c<@http://localhost:8888/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:29677
 undefined
jquery.min.js:2:30920
TypeError: jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function
```

And i look the page source and see, the load order of the js files is wrong, it goes like this in the browser:

```
</script><script src="/assets/d69283db/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/d69283db/yii.validation.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/d69283db/yii.activeForm.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/js/login.js"></script>
```

And in my asset file, the settings are:

AppLoginAsset.php:

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

```
class AppLoginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        '/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css',
        '/dist/css/adminlte.min.css',
        '/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700'
    ];
    public $js = [
        '/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js',
        '/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
        '/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js',
        '/dist/js/login.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [

    ];
}
```

How can i change the load order, to load jquery before the actual yii asset? I have tried to modify like this:

```
 public $js = [
//            '/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js',  <-- commented this
//            '/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', and this
            '/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js',
            '/dist/js/login.js'
        ];
        public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'
        ];
```

But still errors are the same, and assets for jquery and boostrap are not added for some reason, even though they exist.

Comment: Please post html source code for output somewhere.

Comment: why are you loading the custom jquery file inside the asset manager `AppLoginAsset` ?,which particular version do you want to use on your site for `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue of this is that jQuery does not get loaded first.

Create another bundle that would load strictly jQuery and pass it in the `depends` property of your `AppLoginAsset`, this way, you have full control over dependencies.

LE - So you changed your `depends` and it still does not work.. do you unset (or empty them) anything in the default bundles during the app's bootstrapping process or in the main config file? It looks to me that you wanted custom Bootstrap and jQuery and you probably forgot that you alter those bundles at "runtime".

Also, remove the directories within your `assets` directory so Yii2 would recompose them.